# AngularJS strange behavior with $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, broadcast, watch

I use broadcast to check in my controller if a directive change a variable.

Here is how my broadcast is launched (it works) :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.RELOAD, scope.values);
```

And here I handle the broadcast in my controller :

```
 $scope.$on(EVENTS.RELOAD, reloadCurves);

 function reloadCurves(e, data){
    console.log(exp.curves);

   /* console.log('reload asked : ', data); */

    exp.plate.experiments.forEach(function (element) {
        if (data[element.well] === true){
            exp.curves[element.well] = element;
        }
    });

    console.log(exp.curves);
}
```

And after in another directive I check if my curves variable change with the $watch. This watch work too, when I change manually the variable the watch is triggered.

My problem is strange, in my reloadCurves I have two console.log and they always show the same object, but normally the first console.log have to output en empty array (or an array different of the second console.log) and the second one the result of the foreach.

So angular think the curves variable is not changed and don't throw the watch of my second directive.

What to do ?

EDIT :

I change my reloadCurves to this :

```
function reloadCurves(e, data){
    console.log('reload asked : ', data);
    console.log(exp.curves);
    // Récuperer toute les experiments cochés (celle en true)
    var tab = [];
    exp.plate.experiments.forEach(function (element) {
        if (data[element.well] === true){
            tab[element.well] = element;
        }
    });

    exp.curves = tab;

    console.log(exp.curves);
}
```

So now the first and second console.log are different, but the $watch on the curves doesn't throw

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show the code for the watch. What type of watch are you doing? For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Watch Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I think you're assuming that your forEach loop is iterating at least one time or more. As you're saying you are getting both `console.log` output as same so problem is simple. Your forEach loop is not iterating any time. just put console log inside the forEach loop, you won't get that log. Just check what do you have in `exp.plate.experiments` and you'll be able to fix it.

**Edit**

Looks like you're updating model outside angular world. Just wrap it in `$scope.$apply(fn)`

```
function reloadCurves(e, data){
    console.log('reload asked : ', data);
    console.log(exp.curves);
    // Récuperer toute les experiments cochés (celle en true)
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        var tab = [];
        exp.plate.experiments.forEach(function (element) {
            if (data[element.well] === true){
                tab[element.well] = element;
            }
        });

        exp.curves = tab;
    });
    console.log(exp.curves);
}
```

Comment: I try something but still not able to fix my problem :/ can you look at my EDIT ?